# grep() regex with new line characters

Tags: regex, r

I am totally stuck with regex in R. I use www.regex101.com to check my regex and it seems to work. But in R it doesn't. 
I've read that there are fine and not-so-fine differences between different flavors, but I don't see where these differences are or what to look out for. Is there a way to make more advanced regtex with `lookahead`'s etc. work in R functions like `grep(), sub(), gregexpr()`?

This is my string:

```
x <- "n\n\nwelcome\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhowdy\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhi\nstar\n\n\n\n\ngreetings\nstar"
```

this is my regex:

```
"/(?<=\\n)((?:(?!\\n).)*?)(?=\\nstar)/g"
```

this is what i've tried in R:

```
x <- grep("(?<=\\n)((?:(?!\\n).)*?)(?=\\nstar)",x,perl=TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

OR

```
 x <- grep("/(?<=\\n)((?:(?!\\n).)*?)(?=\\nstar)/g",x,perl=TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

this is the output I would like to get:

```
"welome"        "howdy"         "hi"       "greetings"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Tell us about your extraction rules. Do you want to capture all words, leaving out `star` or what?

Comment: exactly. I want to capture "welcome" "howdy" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be unnecessarily escaping the new line (`\n`) in R. Plus since your x is only a vector of length 1 in R, `grep()` will either match that element or it won't. It won't extract matches within that character value. For that, you would want to use the `gregexpr()` function. How about this

```
x <-"\n\n\nwelcome\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhowdy\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhi\nstar\n\n\n\n\ngreetings\nstar"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<=\n)((?:(?!\n).)*?)(?=\nstar)",x,perl=TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "welcome"   "howdy"     "hi"        "greetings"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just plain old `strsplit`. This will split the string based on `\n`, `n` at the beginning of the string (probably a typo), or `star`.

`nzchar` returns a logical `TRUE` for empty strings and `FALSE` otherwise, and `Filter` filters out the `TRUE`s

```
x <- "n\n\nwelcome\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhowdy\nstar\n\n\n\n\nhi\nstar\n\n\n\n\ngreetings\nstar"

Filter(nzchar, strsplit(x, '\n|^n|star')[[1]])

# [1] "welcome"   "howdy"     "hi"        "greetings"
```